# Compare two array and change properties accordingly

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, filter

I have two Array named prodArray and orderArray like following

```
prodArray = [
 {productId : 1 , productName: 'abc', checked: false},
 {productId : 2 , productName: 'def', checked: false},
 {productId : 3 , productName: 'ghi', checked: false},
 {productId : 4 , productName: 'jkl', checked: false}
]

orderArray = [
  {productId : 1 , productName: 'abc'},
  {productId : 4 , productName: 'jkl'}
]
```

I want to compare these two and create a result array like following

```
resultArray = [
  {productId : 1 , productName: 'abc', checked: true},
  {productId : 2 , productName: 'def', checked: false},
  {productId : 3 , productName: 'ghi', checked: false},
  {productId : 4 , productName: 'jkl', checked: true}
]
```

What I have tried so far is as follows without any luck

```
let resultArray = Array.from(new Set(prodArray .filter(f => {
                     return orderArray.some(o => {
                      return f.productId  === o.productId ;
                      });
                    }).filter(x => x.checked === true)));
```

Could anyone please Help ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the `Set` and assign a new object for the result set.

```js
var prodArray = [{ productId: 1 , productName: 'abc', checked: false }, { productId: 2 , productName: 'def', checked: false }, { productId: 3 , productName: 'ghi', checked: false }, { productId: 4 , productName: 'jkl', checked: false }],
    orderArray = [{ productId: 1 , productName: 'abc' }, { productId: 4 , productName: 'jkl' }],
    orders = new Set(orderArray.map(({ productId }) => productId)),
    result = prodArray.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, { checked: orders.has(o.productId) }));
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map()` and `find()`. Following are the steps:

- Apply `map()` the `prodArray`
- `return` an object with all the previous properties but change the `checked`
- Apply `find()` on `orderArray` and set the result as the `checked` property of the returning object from return.

```js
let prodArray = [
 {productId : 1 , productName: 'abc', checked: false},
 {productId : 2 , productName: 'def', checked: false},
 {productId : 3 , productName: 'ghi', checked: false},
 {productId : 4 , productName: 'jkl', checked: false}
]

let orderArray = [
  {productId : 1 , productName: 'abc'},
  {productId : 4 , productName: 'jkl'}
]

let res = prodArray
               .map(x => ({...x,
                         checked:Boolean(orderArray.find(a => 
                            a.productId === x.productId && a.productName === x.productName))}
                ))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: @NabaragPaul You should accept the answer with which you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `new Set()` variable that contains all the `productId`. Use `map` to loop thru each `prodArray` and use check if the set has the `productId`

```js
var prodArray = [{"productId":1,"productName":"abc","checked":false},{"productId":2,"productName":"def","checked":false},{"productId":3,"productName":"ghi","checked":false},{"productId":4,"productName":"jkl","checked":false}];
var orderArray = [{"productId":1,"productName":"abc"},{"productId":4,"productName":"jkl"}]

let productIDs = new Set(orderArray.map(o => o.productId));

let result = prodArray.map(o => ({ ...o,checked: productIDs.has(o.productId)}));

console.log(result);
```